# What do I need to assign a F1 - F12 key to a specific command on my MacBook?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

Is there a way for me to assign a <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> key to a specific command on my MacBook?

This is what I am trying to do:

- <kbd>F1</kbd> = <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
- <kbd>F2</kbd> = <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: @Tom I'm not too sure the OP meant `Fn+1` rather than `F1`. Since they used the `+` separator for the equivalents I guess they meant `F1`. D. Thomas, if that's not what you meant, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, in your *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, just reassign these.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Note that this assigns the <kbd>F</kbd> keys, and not the actual <kbd>Fn</kbd> key *per se*. This is not possible as it just toggles between using the action keys and the standard <kbd>F</kbd> keys, as defined in the same Preference Pane.